# C# MVC-4 How to decrease page load time with use of random order of entity (.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()))

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

**This is what I have:**

In my SQL Server database there are around 4500 vehicles listed from different vendors. The main vehicle table has Key constraints with multiple tables. I have a scheduler which parses number of CSV files and keeps adding more vehicles every night in that table. These CSVs may have vehicles from different vendors or may be there is only a single vendor.

**What I require:**

In site's home page I need to list 20 vehicles in a random manner of vendors so that it does not come up with a single vendor, meaning with every page reload the list keeps changing by vendors. To be exact, in the list there should be vehicles from different vendors. It is not required to be the latest vehicles added.

**My main query:**

```
public IEnumerable<Vehicle> GetRandomVehiclesForHomepage()
{
   var r = new Random();
   var skip = r.Next(0, 100);
   var dateIgnoredTill = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-08-31");

   var h = DataContext.Vehicles
      .Where(v => v.IsActive
      && !v.IsDeleted
      && v.Seller.IsActive
      && v.Seller.IsPublic
      && v.VehiclePhotoes.Count > 0
      && v.AddedOn > dateIgnoredTill)
      .Include(c => c.VehicleCategory)
      .Include(s => s.VehiclePosition)
      .Include(m => m.Manufacturer)
      .Include(p => p.VehiclePhotoes)
      .Include(cp => cp.VehiclePhoto)
      .Include(seller => seller.Seller) //Vendor
      .Include(vcount => vcount.Seller.Vehicles)
      .Include(parish => parish.Seller.StateParish)
      .Include(dh => dh.DriveHand)
      .Include(at => at.AdType)
      .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
      .Take(100).Skip(skip);

   return h;
}
```

**Controller action method:**

```
public ActionResult HomePageVehicleList()
{
   //Get 10 dealers in random order
   //Fetch one last added vehicle from each.

   _service = new VehicleService();
   var model = _service.GetRandomVehiclesForHomepage().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Skip(0).Take(15);
   return View(model);
}
```

As far as the records are concerned, they are coming along perfectly OK, but the execution time is too long, which I need to cut down considerably. At the moment it is taking about 15-20 seconds what I need to bring down close to 5-6 seconds. All tables are indexed.

I have caching enabled, which also works fine but of course only after the first time load is made.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult HomePageVehicleList() {
   ...
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1. Tables are Indexed
2. Using minified CSS and JavaScripts
3. Using `async` attribute for loading JavaScript (`<script async type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>`)
4. Image width and height are mentioned in Media Queries (not using `img-responsive` bootstrap class for resizing).

Is there something wrong in my current approach with the query to fetch vehicles? What should I do to cut down the load time?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all how long does it take without the `OrderBy` and second - do you really need all this information brought by all these includes from the start?

Comment: In addition why to have twice ordering and taking only n items? Both in the `GetRandomVehiclesForHomepage` and in the controller?

Comment: Selecting 20 random vehicles from 4,500 ought to take milliseconds. What does the query and execution plan look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith how can I see query execution plan? The reason for two order by are to make first to get 100 vehicles and then again get another random list from them to make sure the list does not load the same results every time. I think I made mistake here, right? And yes, unfortunately all these information needed to use all Incldues :( Because in the list each vehicle  has to display these info!